# Why is kio correct instead of kion?

Tags: pronouns

I was asked to translate the following English sentence into Esperanto.

> I like everything that is on that table.

The correct translation was the following.

> Mi ŝatas ĉion kio estas sur la tablo.

Why is *kio* used instead of *kion*?
Are both correct, or is only *kio* is correct?

Comment: "Ĉion" apartenas al "ŝatas" kaj "kio" apartenas al "estas". Tial ili havas malsamajn finaĵojn.

Answer (score 3):

Only "kio" is correct here. "kion" would be wrong.

"kio" is used as a [relative pronoun](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/subfrazoj#rilata-kio) here, so it's part of the [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause). While that "kio" refers back to "ĉion" (which is the direct object of the main clause and thus bears the "-n" marker), within the relative clause, it acts as the [*subject*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar)) (of the conjugated verb "estas"), so it cannot bear the "-n" object marker (i.e., it cannot be in accusative case).

By the way, while the comma rules of Esperanto might not be formally fixed, it's so usual in Esperanto to delimit relative clauses with commas, that omitting it seems wrong to me here. Thus, I'd write that as

> Mi ŝatas ĉion, kio estas sur la tablo.

Comment: Kiel aldono al la klarigo.
La propozicio estas komplika, ĝi estas kunmeto de simplas propozicioj. Ni povas skribi same tion alimaniere:
Mi ŝatas ĉion. (Tiu) ĉio estas sur la tablo.
aŭ
Mi ŝatas ĉion sur la tablo (nun, ĉi-foje).
aŭ
Ĉio sur la tablo estas ŝatata de mi.

Comment: «Mi ŝatas ĉion. (Tiu) ĉio estas sur la tablo.» laŭ mi havas alian signifon ol «Mi ŝatas ĉion, kio estas sur la tablo.», @va-milushnikov. They would be interchangeably if it was a non-restrictive relative clause (i.e., [literally _everything_](https://imdb.com/title/tt6710474/) would be on the table), but interpreting it as a [restrictive relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Restrictive_and_non-restrictive) makes much more sense here. If you want split the sentence into two sentences «Estas aferoj sur la tablo. Mi ŝatas ĉiujn el ili.» would mostly preserve the meaning.